# Graphql Inline Fragments search options

Tags: graphql, orchardcms

So i am using graphql feature in Orchard to get data from the events type,
each eventsItem has a bag of Event as it shows the image bellow
 [image]

So the problem is that i need to fetch an event with its "**contentItemId**",is there a way to add where clauses in an inline Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are just a way to specify the selection set (i.e. fields) by type at runtime. They are not a way to filter results. GraphQL does not provide any built-in way to filter, sort or otherwise mutate the results -- it's up to each individual service to implement those features. If the schema doesn't expose any argument on the `events`, `bag`, or `contentItems` fields to let you do the sort of filtering you're trying to do, then it's not possible to do so through a query.